# Possible permutations of string based on LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, permutation, linkedhashmap

So this problem has been taunting me for days. Any help is greatly appreciated!
I have made a LinkedHashMap which stores possible combinations for each part of a string and I'm trying to get all the permutations in an ArrayList of Strings, while maintaing the string order.
For example if the map is:
`a=ab, b=c`
The combinations would be:

```
ab
ac
abb
abc
```

I have tried simply looping each keys and values list, heap's algorithm which didn't work out for keeping the order of elements and also tried using recursion but i wasn't sure how. If anyone could point me in the right direction or hint me, that would be great. Thanks

Another map example of what im trying to do.

If the map is:
`A=a, B=b`

 Output is:

```
AB (key1, key2)
Ab (key1, value2)
aB (value1, key2)
ab (value1, value2)
```

I basically want every combination of the whole map in order while alternating between keys and values of the map.

Comment: Can you explain how a=ab, b=c gets turned into ab ac abb abc? I don't see the relationship.

Comment: Sorry, i probably didnt explain this well. Each key and value of the map is basically part of the main string which could be the key or the value. In this example first part of the string could either be a or ab and second part could either be b or c. I'm trying to find all the possible combinations

Comment: *I have tried many ways and have been unsuccesful so far.* What did you try? Please edit the post with all relevant information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer kiner_shah. I have edited the question

Comment: I'm with @sweeper. I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Could you give an example of a small map (like 2-3 entries) plus the desired output? It seems that a `LinkedHashMap` has a predictable order when iterating over it. Whatever you're trying to do, I'm sure this implementation is part of a sane, fast solution.

Comment: I reedited the question and added more clarification and another full example. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
static List<String> possiblePermutations(Map<String, String> map) {
    int size = map.size();
    List<Entry<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    new Object() {
        void perm(int i, String s) {
            if (i >= size) {
                result.add(s);
                return;
            }
            Entry<String, String> entry = list.get(i);
            perm(i + 1, s + entry.getKey());
            perm(i + 1, s + entry.getValue());
        }
    }.perm(0, "");
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("a", "ab");
    map.put("b", "c");
    map.put("x", "y");
    List<String> result = possiblePermutations(map);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

output:

```
[abx, aby, acx, acy, abbx, abby, abcx, abcy]
```

Comment: Thank you!! Exactly what i needed! You just saved my day! :)

Answer (score -1):

It's very simple ...

1. Let's say the number of entries in your map is `N`
2. There is a 1-to-1 mapping between each possible permutation of such strings and an array `boolean` of length `N`. If the array has a `true` in position `K`, we pick the key from map entry `K`, otherwise we pick the value.
3. Therefore, to generate all possible permutations you need to [generate all possible boolean arrays](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-all-the-binary-strings-of-n-bits/) (same as binary numbers) of length `N` and then use each one to create a corresponding string.

Comment: If something is unclear, add a comment and I'll explain further or send a code sample

Comment: Thank you!! I was hoping for a simpler faster way of course, though I will definitely try this right now and let you know.

Comment: Its a pretty standard approach in combinatorial algorithms, when its hard to generate all permutations of entity X, but it is easy to generate all permutations of entity Y for which there exists a one to one correspondence with X.

Comment: That doesn't sound right to me. If you can make all combinations of a key, you can make all combinations of a value with roughly the same code. I'm also unsure how you know what @LoneLearner is asking since his example didn't expose his desired output that well. You seem extremely confident about a weakly specified problem.

Comment: Its a standard combinatorial problem. You have N choices to make and each choice has K options, and then you are asked how many possible choice combinations can you make. In this problem the number of choice N is equal to the number of entries in the map. K is equal to 2, since we can pick either a key or a value for each entry. Therefore, the answer is 2^N .. and each choice sequence corresponds to a binary string from 0000 to 1111 (for N=4).

Comment: I wasn't able to implement it yet. Not sure how to make this work. Sorry, I'm not so experienced in algorithms yet.